# How to time reactive function in Shiny app in r

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a function that I would like to time, and then display on the UI how much time it took to execute that function. How can I get the execution time of that function re-actively? I have tried to put the variable in the reactive function, around the function, etc. I just want to time how long it takes for the reactive function to run and then display it. I am trying not to use additional packages.

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    # User Input Text  Box
    textInput(inputId = "userText",
          label = "",
          placeholder = "Type in a partial sentence here..."),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "textInput", placeholder = TRUE),

    # Show amount of execution time
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "timer", placeholder = TRUE)  
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Declare Timer variables
  startTime <- Sys.time()
  endTime <- Sys.time()

  # Some function to time: Trivial Paste Function
  textToDisplay <- reactive({
    req(input$userText)
    startTime <- Sys.time()
    textToDisplay <- paste("This is the user input text: ", input$userText)
    endTime <- Sys.time()
    return(textToDisplay)
  })

  # Display pasted text
  output$textInput <- renderText({
    req(input$userText)
    textToDisplay()

  })

  # Display execution time
  output$timer <- renderText({
    req(input$userText)
    paste0("Executed in: ",((endTime - startTime)*1000)," milliseconds")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code above does not update or show the proper time difference correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, the problem is that `startTime` and `endTime` aren't reactive values, so when they change they don't cause `renderText` to be invalidated and rerun and they don't persist properly outside the reactive expressions.

Just define a `reactiveValues` object, and make `startTime` and `endTime` part of that.

Replace the part where you define timer variables with:

```
rv <- reactiveValues()
```

Then, each time you call on `startTime` and `endTime`, use `rv$startTime` and `rv$endTime`.

You still won't see a result because `textToDisplay` runs too quickly, but if you make those changes and add `Sys.sleep(2)` into `textToDisplay` you'll see that it works properly.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a bit of unnecessary code there. Your definition of `startTime` and `endTime` both within `server` and the individual reactive chunks is confusing (both to you and the readers); most certainly both locations are not required, and since I prefer the use of `system.time`, I suggest neither location is necessary.

There are two ways to deal with getting two return values (data and elapsed time) from a chunk: (1) return a `list`, and (2) `reactiveValues()`.

Keeping your `ui` and `shinyApp` ...

For the first option (`list`), the `server` component becomes:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  mydat <- eventReactive(input$userText, {
    req(input$userText)
    tm <- system.time({
      Sys.sleep(runif(1))
      out <- paste("This is the user input text:", sQuote(input$userText))
    })
    list(x=out, elapsed=tm['elapsed'])
  })
  # Display pasted text
  output$textInput <- renderText({
    req(mydat())
    mydat()$x
  })
  # Display execution time
  output$timer <- renderText({
    req(mydat())
    paste0("Executed in: ", round(mydat()$elapsed*1000), " milliseconds")
  })
}
```

For the second option, try:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  times <- reactiveVal()
  mydat <- reactiveVal()
  # operates in side-effect
  observeEvent(input$userText, {
    req(input$userText)
    tm <- system.time({
      Sys.sleep(runif(1))
      out <- paste("This is the user input text:", sQuote(input$userText))
    })
    times(tm['elapsed'])
    mydat(out)
  })
  # Display pasted text
  output$textInput <- renderText({
    req(mydat())
    mydat()
  })
  # Display execution time
  output$timer <- renderText({
    req(times())
    paste0("Executed in: ", round(times()*1000), " milliseconds")
  })
}
```

(Instead of two `reactiveVal()` variables, you can also use @divibisan's suggestion to use `reactiveValues()`, the same end-result.)

Comment: Does calling `mydat()` in multiple places like this result in multiple calls to the event reactive function in the first case?

Comment: No. Which "event reactive function" are you referring to?

Comment: `mydat <- eventReactive(input$userText, {...` in the first option. I do something similar, except I run an expensive query which I don't want to repeat.

Comment: Okay. The first time `mydat()` is referenced in some reactive block, it triggers the evaluation of your `eventReactive(input$userText, ...)` block. As long as `input$userText` does not change, every subsequent evaluation of `mydat()` uses a saved value and *does not re-evaluate the `mydat <- eventReactive(...)` block*. Conversely, when `input$userText` changes, `mydat` is re-evaluated (even if expensive) and all that rely on `mydat()` will also be re-evaluated. That's the benefit (and cost) of shiny's reactivity. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. `mydat()` _only_ updates when the given input changes. Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: BTW: though it *can* be a little extra work to see, if you can use [`reactlog`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reactlog/index.html) (the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reactlog/vignettes/reactlog.html) is good), it will show you when blocks are invalidated and re-evaluated. I tend to only use it when I believe/notice that some blocks are triggered more frequently than I expect, but it can be very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

I used an approach that is the combination of your suggestions @r2evans and @divibisan . I used reactiveValues because I think it is user readable and can be extended to other uses very easily. I used system.time as suggested. When the function is run, it updates the reactive values, and a return statement controls returning the appropriate value from the function.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  options(digits.secs=2)

  # Declare Timer variables
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    exTime = Sys.time()
  )

  # Trivial Paste Function
  textToDisplay <- reactive({
    req(input$userText)
    t <- system.time({
      textToDisplay <- paste("This is the user input text: ", 
                             input$userText)
      })
    rv$exTime <- t[[3]]
    return(textToDisplay)
  })

  # Display pasted text
  output$textInput <- renderText({
    req(input$userText)
    textToDisplay()
  })

  # Display execution time
  output$timer <- renderText({
    req(input$userText)
    paste0("Executed in: ",((rv$exTime)*1000)," milliseconds")
  })
}
```

As @divibisan suggested, this will display 0 because the code runs so fast. You can increase the the digits returned from `system.time()` with `options(digits.secs=2)`, which I added at the top of the server code. For my purposes with the real function, this gave me 10 millisecond precision running in Windows.